# display prompt box on doubleclick on google maps not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

my approach is simple want a prompt box apper on doubleclick on google maps :
user clicks yes (some form is rendered, another page - for now alert box appears)
 if no nothing..
but my code does not do teh work -and the map is OK -i.e -
the add listener is inside
`if(navigator.geolocation)`...
and it's working fine,  maps is centered on my current position and I also but alert box in there

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dbclick', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng,"addEvents.html"); 
});
function placeMarker(location, page){
    if (confirm("wanna add an event?") == true) {
        alert ("add some details"); 
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
        map.setCenter(location);
    } else {
        alert ("cancel adding event"); 
}
                        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example in the form of JSFiddle?

Comment: you havent passed your map to to the `placeMarker` function. also when you say your code does not work, what about it doesnt work?

Comment: I mean the map itself is working, yeah but I forget to pass that map parameter thnaks that'll be the cause

Comment: but lookin at oficial google docs it should be OK - taht i haven't pass the map    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it works - problem was with that doubleclick - cause it's default event for zooming in, it still should work but it doesn't, so i changed 'dbclick' to 'click' and it works